# File name and size are getting duplicated when saved in database table

Tags: java, file-io

I have the following code in doPost in Servlet class.

The problem I am facing is sometimes, when I save records in database table, fileName and size is getting repeated, i.e. more than once same file name and size are getting inserted, however when it is saved to directory all files are saved with out any duplicates.

e.g. If I am saving 10 files names, `spring-security-ntlm-3.0.2.SNAPSHOT.jar` is repeated twice leaving `jsf-api-2.0.3.jar`, however files are written correctly to file server

What could be the reason for this and how can I resolve the issue?

```
List<FileItem> items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item: items) {
            fileName = item.getName();
            if (fileName != null) {

                fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileName);
            }

            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                File file = new File(folderName + fileName);
                    item.write(file);
                    projectList = new ArrayList<Project>();
                    projectList.add(lessonAttachment);
                    for (Project obj: projectList) {
                        obj.setProjectId("M2K90");
                        obj.setFileName(fileName);
                        Integer size = (int)(long)item.getSize();
                        obj.setSize(size);
                        myDAO.saveProject(projectList);
                    }
            }

        }
```

Comment: It doesnt look like you are loading the object, before you save over it. It appears that you are creating a projectlist and adding an item, then looping through that project list and saving it. If you want to overwrite the lessonAttachment object then you need to load it, then overwrite what you loaded. This code is going to add too the project list a new item each time, then it will attempt to save it. I suggest putting a breakpoint in and debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`projectList` will save number of times of `projectList` size.  `myDAO.saveProject(projectList);` should be outside of for loop.

Comment: Masud, Thanks for pointing this out. Even after putting that statement outside for loop, it does insert duplicate file names when I insert to table. e.g. If I am saving 10 files names, `spring-security-ntlm-3.0.2.SNAPSHOT.jar` is repeated twice leaving `jsf-api-2.0.3.jar`, however files are written correctly to file server.

Comment: Your code didn't unveil the reason of duplicate insert. Try to put a break point and debug.